# findViewById returns null for a ScrollView

Tags: android, null, scrollview, findviewbyid

I am trying to call the invalidate() method of the ScrollView but it gives me an error that the ScrollView is null. However, I can reference all the views inside the Scroll View. Here is my code, where I was checking whether "prueba" is null or not. v is initialized in onActivityCreated() method of the fragment, which I also attached as well as the onCreatedView(), with its XML.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflador, ViewGroup contenedor, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View vista = inflador.inflate(R.layout.vista_lugar, contenedor, false);
        return vista;
    }

 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){
        super.onActivityCreated(state);
        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            pos = extras.getInt("pos", 0);
        } else {
            pos = 0;
        }

        v = getView();
        _id = ((Aplicacion)getActivity().getApplication()).adaptador.idPosicion(pos);
        lugares = ((Aplicacion)getActivity().getApplication()).lugares;
        usoLugar = new CasosUsoLugar(getActivity(), this, lugares,((Aplicacion)getActivity().getApplication()).adaptador);
        lugar = ((Aplicacion)getActivity().getApplication()).adaptador.lugarPosicion(pos);
        foto = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.foto);

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RESULTADO_EDITAR) {
            lugar = lugares.elemento(_id);
            pos = ((Aplicacion)getActivity().getApplication()).adaptador.posicionId(_id);
            ScrollView prueba = v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
            if(prueba != null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroll no es nula", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroll SI es nula", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
}
```

And the XML vista_lugar is:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Nombres del lugar"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_tipo"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="logo del tipo"
                android:src="@drawable/otros" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tipo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="tipo del lugar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/barra_mapa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_dir"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="logo de la dire"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dire_lugar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="dirección del lugar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/barra_telefono"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_tel"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="logo del telefono"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="telefono del lugar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/barra_url"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_web"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="logo de la web"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="web del lugar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_info"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="logo de la información"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="informacion del lugar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_fecha"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="logo de la fecha"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fecha"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="fecha"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/logo_fecha"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_hora"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="logo de la hora"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_recent_history"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fecha"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hora"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hora"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/logo_hora"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/valoracion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:rating="3" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/foto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="fotografía"
                android:src="@drawable/foto_epsg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/camara"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:contentDescription="logo cámara"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/galeria"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:contentDescription="logo cámara"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/borrar_foto"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:contentDescription="Eliminar foto"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to replace `ScrollView prueba = v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);` inside onCreate() method below inflador.inflate(R...
and rename v to vista
and [read](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) what is `onActivityResult` 
))))
it is absolutely not for this situation

you will have

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflador, ViewGroup contenedor, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View vista = inflador.inflate(R.layout.vista_lugar, contenedor, false);
    ScrollView prueba = vista.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

    return vista;
}
```

and delete your onActivityResult()
if you want to do something with your scrollview - just make it as global variable

Comment: Yeah, it worked! But I don´t really understand why, cause I have other methods in the fragment that use `v.findViewById(R.id...)` to refer to Views inside the ScrollView, and they all work fine!

Comment: @marpe method onActivityResult() is called after you change activity with result obtaining. it is not related to fragments or your situation at all. read my link above. it is regular thing and I'm sure that you will meet it many times